# CRTL+V (Paste) function automatic formatting in JavaScript asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my current project, I have a textbox where the user will enter some numeric ID (like a product ID) -- For example: `12345-123-1234567-12345`.

I want to have a JavaScript in my aspx page that, when a user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste in text, will format that text irrespective of the text's present format.

For example, if the text is in formatted like `12345---123-123456712345` then the function will format it to `12345-123-1234567-12345`.

**EDIT:**

Tried your Suggetion but it's not working. I tried like this way... below code sample

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  Text="" ></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    var tb = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
    tb.OnTextChanged = function () {

        this.value = this.value.replace("---", "-");
    }; 

</script>
```

It's erroring out saying

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property
>   'OnTextChanged': object is null or undefined

Comment: A quick regex could handle that, "[^(0-9)]". Replace all of them with "". If you need dashes in between, you can iterate through and add them afterwards

Comment: replacing/adding dashes is no big deal ... I am just wonder how will I capture CRTL+V in javascript. as said am pretty new to JS ... not much sure. can you post an edxample .... if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a textbox whenever its text is change, you can use the "onchange" event (just note that the change won't happen until focus leaves the textbox)

First, give your textbox a unique id—asp.net version 4 has features that allow you to give form elements id's that won't be "messed with"—then set the onchange event.

```
var tb = document.getElementById("textBoxId");
tb.onchange = function() {
   //I think you want:
   this.value = this.value.replace("---", "-");
};
```

---

**EDIT**

You can catch the `keyup` event, and check to see if the user has just hit control-v.  If so, you can modify the textbox's current value.  Just note that this will **not** work if the user pastes by right clicking.

The best way to handle this is with the onchange event, which will work no matter how the textbox is changed.

```
   document.getElementById("tb").onkeyup = function (e) {
       var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
       if (e.which === 86 && e.ctrlKey)
           alert("you pasted " + this.value);
   };
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vWzGU/)

Comment: Adam: I will try it out and can you please add the text again which you deleted with EDIT ... was getting some idea :)

Comment: @Rahul - the deleted text wasn't of much value.  I was just setting this.value to some local variable, which is pointless.

Comment: Thanks Adam but where will I call this function inside another JS function?

Comment: You'd want to set this handler up inside the window.onload event, or you can put this code in a script section at the end of your body

Comment: Thanks for your response ... I tried it but it's errored out. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yep Yep, the edited answer worked for me ... Great Thanks. +1 for your help.